# How to get specific values from a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Im trying to understand how i can write a PHP syntax to get the value from a given a PHP array with definition.

```
//given definition
$php_array=array(“index1”=>array(“value1”,”value2”,“value3”),
         “index2”=>“value4”,
         “index3”=>array([0]=>“value5”,[1]=>“value6”,
             [2]=>“value7”),
         “index4”=>array([“index5”]=>“value8”,
             [“index6”]=>array(“value9”,”value10”)))
```

I'm trying to get "value 3", "value 6" and "value "9".

How do I do that?

Comment: Hi, you should format your code with the "code sample" button for readability.

Comment: What is the problem you have? Isn't it just `$php_array['index1'][2]`?

Comment: the expected output is 
"value 3"
"value 6"
"value 9"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that we wish to loop through and extract the desired values, and do other things, which we can do so.

---

Here, we have a main [array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) with some other arrays inside the array. They have indices (keys) and values.

Our desired outputs can be simply found in these three places:

```
$php_array["index1"][2];
$php_array["index3"][1];
$php_array["index4"]["index6"][0];
```

where 2, 1 and 0 are the keys of nested or inside arrays in the main array:

#### Main Array

```
$php_array = array(
    "index1" => ["value1", "value2", "value3"],
    "index2" => "value4",
    "index3" => ["value5", "value6", "value7"],
    "index4" => [
        "index5" => "value8",
        "index6" => ["value9", "value10"],
    ],
);
```

#### Example

Here, we loop in our main array, which has four indices. Whenever the `index` is `===` to our desired value, the program `echo` or print our desired value, otherwise does nothing:

```
$php_array = array(
    "index1" => ["value1", "value2", "value3"],
    "index2" => "value4",
    "index3" => ["0" => "value5", "1" => "value6", "2" => "value7"],
    "index4" => ["index5" => "value8", "index6" => ["value9", "value10"]],
);

foreach ($php_array as $key => $value) {
    if ($key === "index1") {
        echo $value["2"];
    }

    if ($key === "index3") {
        echo $value["1"];

    }

    if ($key === "index4") {
        echo $value["index6"]["0"];
    }

}
```

#### Output

```
value3
value6
value9
```

### References

[image]

[image]

#### [Video](https://clevertechie.com/php/3/php-array)

Comment: possible that the output doesnt have "string(6)"?

Comment: I just started learning PHP so would you mind explaining the solution code in a simple way? thank you ><

Answer (score 0):

Your values are in these variables:

```
$php_array['index1'][2];
$php_array['index3'][1];
$php_array['index4']['index6'][0];
```

Comment: @ChloeLim there is nothing wrong with those statements. Might be related to what you put before it.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can format your array like this:

```
$php_array = array(
    "index1"=>array("value1","value2","value3"),
    "index2"=>"value4",
    "index3"=>array(
        "value5", "value6","value7"
    ),
    "index4"=>array(
        "index5"=>"value8",
        "index6"=>array(
            "value9","value10"
        )
    )
);

$value3 = $php_array['index1'][2];
$value6 = $php_array['index3'][1];
$value9 = $php_array['index4']['index6'][0];
```